# Change Nlohmann json key-value with increment function? c++

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

Instead of this:

```
j["skills"]["atk"] = j["skills"]["atk"].get<int>() + 6;
```

I want something like this:

```
void json_inc(json ref, int value) //function to increment int key-values
{
    ref = ref.get<int>() + value;
}

json_inc(j["skills"]["atk"], 6); //adds 6
```

Is this possible for nested json objects like above?

Comment: I don't know. Is it? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yup, doesnt change the value in `j["skills"]["atk"]`. Hoping someone knows a way that does.

Comment: I do not know the internal structure of this particular JSON Library, but 'in general', if you want to manipulate the content of a variable within a function, you either need to pass the variable itself as a pointer or, in C++, as reference using the `&` operator. This `json` object you are passing is likely to do that under the hood though.

Comment: Try stepping into the function call with your debugger. Figure out, whether what you are passing is a `copy` of the object, or a `pointer`/`reference`. If it is a `copy` (as suggested), figure out, how you can make it a reference. Then you've got your solution.

Comment: I'm super new to c++, I would just `j["skills"]["atk"]&` to pass it as a reference?

Comment: No. The correct syntax to pass anything as reference is to do it in the function header. So it'd be: `void json_inc(json &ref, int value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your json object `by value`. This means, that the object will, in fact, be duplicated in memory and whatever changes you make to the object will ceased to exist once you leave the scope of the function.

To actually manipulate the variable you are passing (and this works for any kind of C++ variable), you need to `pass by reference`.

This is done by changing the prototype of your function to `void json_inc(json &ref, int value)`.

The `&` operator means 'reference' in C++. Under the hood, this reference is an immutable `pointer` to the variable you are passing, performing any changes you do directly on the variable you are passing instead of a copy.

For larger structures, it is just about almost desirable to `pass by reference`, because it eliminates the need to copy the object on the stack (after all, only the original variable needs to exist).

If you should venture into C at some point (where references do not exist), you can achieve the same thing with pointers:

```
void json_inc(json *ref, int value) //function to increment int key-values
{
    *ref = ref->get<int>() + value;
}

json_inc(&j["skills"]["atk"], 6); //adds 6
```